# Moved EE1.7.1 site to new server and can't log into CP

Tags: control-panel, login, server-migration

I want to upgrade my EE1.7.1 installation to EE2. My existing site has been in existence since the early days of pmachine and so has a lot of legacy plugins, etc including the image gallery, a discussion forum, etc. So, before just blindly upgrading, I want to do a "practice run". I copied my data base and files to a new server hosted by EngineHosting following the instructions for migrating to a new server.

While I can access the index page of the new site okay, I cannot log into the CP in order to change all the settings I need to change to complete the migration. (I plan to use Deeploy which is installed in the migrated site.)

When I enter my login and password (using the correct credentials), I am just taken back to the CP login page. (If I use incorrect credentials, I get an error message that my username or password is incorrect.)

I've seen similar posts that blame cookies for this, but I don't think that is the problem. I've cleared my browser cache and cookies, tried several browsers, etc.

I've had this question posted over at the EE site for a while and someone kindly directed me here, thinking someone might be able to help coach me through resolving this issue.

Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following at the end of your configs in the config.php file:

```
$conf['secure_forms'] = "n";
$conf['cookie_domain'] = "";
$conf['cookie_path'] = "";
$conf['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$conf['admin_session_type'] = "cs";
$conf['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$conf['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n";
```

MOST LIKELY THE ISSUE IS THIS LINE:

```
$conf['cookie_path'] = "";
```

Comment: Just to add that whenever this has happened me in the past on migrating a site, it's always been down specifically to the cookie domain - the cookie domain setting in the CP related to the old domain. By adding the lines Anna suggests to your config file, the cookie domain will be empty as well as several other settings being relaxed/reset, and you should be able to login. If not, try using $conf['cookie_domain']='.yournewdomain.com'; instead

Comment: Brilliant. Anna's suggestion got me logged in! I don't have any css applied to the control panel (and I see it in my themes folder), so that is the next thing to tackle. I used deeploy helper to change all references to my old domain, but still no css. Site itself looks fine. Thanks for the help. Any idea on the css is welcomed ;-)

Comment: Got the CSS working too. Needed to update all server paths, not just URLs.

Comment: Now that the site is running and I have access to the CP and have changed all settings, should I remove the settings Anna recommended?

Comment: Remove one line at a time and then check the login.