# EE1 moving to new server; cant login

Tags: ee1, nginx

I have moved my EE1 instance to a new server running nginx.

The home page loads up and the control panel login page loads up but when I try login I see the session information pass through but the control panel doesnt actually load up. It just goes back to the login page.

I have tried these changes in the config.php file:

[Moved EE1.7.1 site to new server and can't log into CP](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/moved-ee1-7-1-site-to-new-server-and-cant-log-into-cp)

But they didnt work.

Ideas?

Comment: Is the site running on the same domain as before?  I agree with the comments in answer that you linked to that the problem is most likely with cookie domain.

Comment: No, the domain has changed.

Comment: Outside of the config file, whats another way to clear the cookie cache? The cache files in the system folder have been emptied already.

Comment: You can connect via mysql... looking up details now.

Comment: Did you try setting the config: $conf['cookie_domain'] = "whatever.yournewdomain.com";

Comment: Yep i can connect via mysql

Comment: I will try that in a sec

Comment: You can connect via mysql, but it's no picnic. You want the site_system_preferences column from the exp_sites table. All the preferences are in that one field stored in what looks like a serial array.

Comment: So looks like my config changes are actually hitting the db.