# Moved EE 2.8.1 to new server cannot log-in

Tags: control-panel, cookies

I guess that technically I am not moving to a new server, but rather a new installation to create a dev environment to work on before pushing to prod site. I have followed instructions here several times starting fresh each time:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

The issue is that after moving the files and importing db to new install I am unable to log-in to the control panel. If I type in the wrong credentials, I get the "wrong username/password" error--which i don't get if i use the right credentials, but the right credentials just won't log me in.

I have:

1. double/triple checked the cp url in config.php/database.php
2. made sure permissions were set per instructions in the link above
3. cleared browser cookies/cache
4. even have had friends check from their computer (computer that had never visited the site before)

Still no solution. I found this question-- which seems to be what I am experiencing:

[Moved EE1.7.1 site to new server and can't log into CP](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/moved-ee1-7-1-site-to-new-server-and-cant-log-into-cp)

This did has not solved my issue.

What could I be missing?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Do you have the Structure extension installed?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies?

Comment: That question didn't solve your issue because it's for EE 1.X install. I marked your question as a duplicate and linked it to the EE2 config code to add to your config file.

Comment: thanks Anna for linking to the config file - that didn't help either, I had tried it as well before posting. The mystery of the bug remains. In the end I had to do a clean install of EE (did this several times before I got it to work, same process, it just started working).